# Upgrade to iOS Google FirebaseSDK 9.0 above causing crash even though calling FirebaseApp.config

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swift-package-manager, xcode14.3

Upgraded firebasesdk to 10.11 from 8.9 then UnitTests are failing with error saying FirebaseApp.config has to be called before accessing RemoteConfig. Then added FirebaseApp.config to the FakeAppDelegate that we are using for UnitTests. Then observing below error related to FBLPromise firebaseinstallationID. Saw other links about -Objc to be added to OtherFlags even that didn't work. we have Swift Package for getting firebase dependency no CocoaPods. Did Anyone implemented UnitTests with new FirebaseSDK?

[image: crash after adding firebaseApp.config to testAppDelegate for UnitTests.]